# Is It Possible to Get the Windows 7 OS Back?

Tags: windows-7, system-restore

I accidentally wiped the Windows 7 OS while trying to make a persistent USB for Linux Mint.

I still have a full image of Windows 7 made by using Macrium, the problem is there is no Windows 7 on the laptop anymore.

When I boot the laptop onto Linux Mint, I looked at the drives on GParted: I can see that there is the recover partition for Windows 7 still on the c drive. I attached the screenshot for drives showing on Gparted. As you can see: sda3 is where Windows 7 was installed.

Is there a way to get the Windows 7 OS back?

[image: GParted_screenshot]

Comment: If you have a Macrium image, you should be able to boot with the Macrium USB recovery disk and use the image it made.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

I've finally managed to restore Windows 7 from Macrium image by using the PE recovery iso made by using Macrium as well. Thanks everyone.

Answer (score 0):

You might be able to recover the partition using recovery software like:

- [TestDisk](https://www.cgsecurity.org/wiki/TestDisk)
- [EaseUS](https://www.easeus.com/)
- [others](https://www.google.com/search?q=partition%20recovery%20free&oq=partiti&aqs=chrome.0.69i59l2j0l4.1819j0j4&sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8)

The ability to do so will entirely depend on what actions you took.

You also said you have a Macrium backup.  I assume you didnt make a recovery disk inside of Macrium.  This disk would allow you to boot off of it and restore from a backup.

Comment: I have a repair cd and a full image on usb, the problem is when I boot up laptop, it said no OS found. (The first error was: Unknown filesystem, Grub rescue, I tried to fix the mbr and rebuildbcd in Command Line, but after that I lost the windows recovery options, so I cannot get to Macrium any more.) Does this make sense?

Comment: You need another Windows PC where to install Macrium and from there make the Macrium USB bootable media, something you should have done before as it pretty much is the point of creating backups that often need to be recovered in situations such as yours.